# Android sms manager not sending sms

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

Am new for android . I want send sms after click send button

1. first i have used sms manager api.

> ```
> package com.example.smsproject;
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.telephony.SmsManager;
> import android.view.View;`enter code here`
> import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
> public class Page2Activity extends Activity {
>
>   Button button;
>   EditText textPhoneNo;
>   @Override
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
>       button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
>       textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobilenumber);
>
>       button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
>           @Override
>
>       public void onClick(View v){
>
>       //String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
>       String phoneNo = "tel:xxxxxxxxxx";
>       String messageText = "SMS FROM ANDROID";
>       try {
>           SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
>           smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, messageText, null, null);
>           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent Successfully!",
>                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>       }catch (Exception e){
>
>           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
>                   "SMS failed, please try again later ! ",
>                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>           e.printStackTrace();
>
>       }
>
>           }
>
>       });
>
>   }
>
> }
> ```

1. set send_sms permission on android_manifest.xml

i got zero errors but sms not sending. If you have know answer.

please let me know, thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you sending SMS from real device or Emulator?

Comment: using Emulator only..

Comment: You should send message using real device not with Emulator...

Answer (score 23):

To complete @Android Fanatic answer

If the text is too long, the message does not go away, you have to respect max length depending of encoding.

More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348086/sms-manager-send-mutlipart-message-when-there-is-less-than-160-characters).

I'd prefer this method

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);

ArrayList<PendingIntent> sendList = new ArrayList<>();
sendList.add(sentPI);

ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliverList = new ArrayList<>();
deliverList.add(deliveredPI);

sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sendList, deliverList);
```

Comment: Thanks, was useful for long sms text. +1

Answer (score 7):

Also SMS Manager doesn't sent messages if the message is longer than 160 for English text, and 70 for 16-bit alphabet text. Try sending small English text to see if it's the case. 
(You can sent multiple part messages to send long texts).

Answer (score 1):

```
String incomming = "9876543210";
android.telephony.SmsManager sms=android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(incomming, null,"Here Is Sms", null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.d("SMS ready to send", "----FIRST CALL----");
String number = "111111111111"; //ed1.getText().toString();
String message =  "Test SMS DATA"; //ed2.getText().toString();

Log.d("SMS ready to send", "----SECOND CALL----"+number);
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);

Log.d("SMS ready to send", "----THIRD CALL----");
```